# Implementing python traceback

Tags: python, traceback

Any idea where to implement `traceback.format_exc()` and `traceback.print_exc()`. 
They are fundamentally different as their `names` suggest but I want to understand how implementation differs. Any insight would be helpful.

Comment: [`traceback.print_exception`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exception) [`traceback.format_exception`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception) might help you.

Comment: you can do using try and except block and catch block you can add traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```py
try:
    #line of code 

except Exception as e:
       exe_stack_trace = traceback.format_exc()
       print("Error while fetching client and project information---", exe_stack_trace)
```

reference : 
https://github.com/aviboy2006/clearglass-test/blob/master/cost_explorer_controller.py